# WPF image Animation based on network responce

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

Inside our WPF application We have IObservable which gets populated from our server. as we are moving to new .NET 4.5 features (async, await), at first we only load ReturnItems withou image an after its successful download we use Parallel.Foreach() to load associated images as well.

when image download completes for each item byte[] is assigned to ReturnItems CoverImage property and from my UI DataTemplate s Image element is bound to this property as well.

What I want to achieve is animate this image load process so there is some sort of fadein from nothing animation when image completes loading. I want to use storyboards if possible.

Comment: Can you show us your current attempt? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I do not have one loading of data from web works perfectly I am interested in WPF XAML part of this task. and where we have nothing implemented yet just a sample datatemplate with Image element inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that before you set the source of the image it is `null`, i.e. it's not an empty array or similar. If so, use this style for the image:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleImageFadeIn"
       TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity"
            Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!--Sets visibility to Collapsed if Source is null - this will cause IsVisible to be false-->
        <Trigger Property="Source"
                 Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--Fades-in the image when it becomes visible-->
        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             To="1"
                                             Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <!--This (ExitActions) is only necessary if the image is "loosing" its source at run-time-->
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             To="0"
                                             Duration="0:0:0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think this works perfectly I just want to know if this is optimized solution from the performance perspective?

Comment: It shouldn't cause memory leaks, as far as I know. The animation itself is demanding but should be handled by the GPU so it should work OK.

Comment: There is some strange behavior in this style declaration. at the very first load of the image it fades in but after I remove image it does not fade out and reataching image does not trigger fadein animation as e result it simply shows up

Comment: How do you remove the image?